# How to work with custom css fonts?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, font-face

I'm trying to use a custom CSS font on an Intranet website I'm working on but internet Explorer ignores it.

Can any one help me?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "samaritans-webfont";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src:url("/smresources/fonts/samaritans-webfont.eot?iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
  url("/smresources/fonts/samaritans-webfont.woff") format("woff"), 
  url("/smresources/fonts/samaritans-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), 
  url("/smresources/fonts/samaritans-webfont.svg#samaritans-webfont") format("svg");
}
```

Comment: What the exact version of IE you're talking about?

Comment: @Pavlo Mykhalov , I'm testing on IE9. Many thanks for you quick response

Comment: First of all, you are missing closing curly bracket.

Comment: @Pavlo Mykhalov, the curly bracket is lost when i pasted it here but in my code I have it

Comment: One more: what server are you using? IIS/Apache/other?

Comment: Where did you get the font from? The most probable explanations appears to be that the .eot file is broken.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - IE9 uses .WOFF over .EOT

Answer (score 1):

If you are on IE9 then -

When `@font-face` is used on an IIS server, IE9 users may not see the font. This can be solved in two ways. 1) Add the WOFF format to the list of MIME types. or 2) change the format('eot') portion to format('embedded-opentype'). Either one will solve issues with IE9.

[**The New Bulletproof @Font-Face Syntax**](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)

Comment: I'm using 'embedded-opentype' for the eot. can you elaborate it please. i think i didn't get you on that.

Comment: I'm using 'embedded-opentype' for the eot. can you elaborate it please. i think i didn't get you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of IE there is varying support.

Note: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface If you see that you can see support for different versions of IE varies, so if your on IE 6 you will need extra hacks to get web fonts working.